# Application not loading after DFU:Leave

Tags: stm32, dfu

I am trying to program the STM32F401 flash on our board in DFU mode. I am using the dfu-util tool in my linux computer.For my project requirements the BOOT 0 pin is always kept high throughout the process.

I am using the following command to flash and jump to application code.

```
dfu-util -a 0 -s 0x08000000:leave -D <location-to-binary>.bin
```

After the flashing is done I can see through 'lsusb' command that sometimes the MCU is not out of DFU boot loader, and sometimes out of it. Either way the application does not start.

When I further try to use the leave command when it's in bootloader, it shows the following log and the above situation continues,

```
Copyright 2005-2009 Weston Schmidt, Harald Welte and OpenMoko Inc.
Copyright 2010-2021 Tormod Volden and Stefan Schmidt
This program is Free Software and has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Please report bugs to http://sourceforge.net/p/dfu-util/tickets/

Opening DFU capable USB device...
Device ID 0483:df11
Device DFU version 011a
Claiming USB DFU Interface...
Setting Alternate Interface #0 ...
Determining device status...
DFU state(10) = dfuERROR, status(10) = Device's firmware is corrupt. It cannot return to run-time (non-DFU) operations
Clearing status
Determining device status...
DFU state(2) = dfuIDLE, status(0) = No error condition is present
DFU mode device DFU version 011a
Device returned transfer size 2048
DfuSe interface name: "Internal Flash  "
DfuSe command mode
Submitting leave request...
Transitioning to dfuMANIFEST state
```

Thanks in advance for any advice or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I had to uncomment the `define USER_VECT_TAB_ADDRESS` in the **system_stm32f4xx.c** file.

Basically what was happening was that bootloader was looking for a loadable vector address from the flash application. With the `USER_VECT_TAB_ADDRESS` commented the pointer to the vector address kept pointing to the bootloader vector table effectively crashing the flash application resetting the controller. With the BOOT 0 pin high it kept loading into bootloader with each reset.

More information about this is available in this similar question:
[STM32G474 bootloader exit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68436562/16758065)